# Updating item in recyclerview, automatically updates viewmodel values even when it must not update - Navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

I am facing a weird problem in my application.

Basic structure of the app is that I have one MainActivity and that has many fragments. Using Navigation component (Sigh! why did I use that).

There's a single MainViewModel() that provides and circulates the data around fragments.

**Problem is** that I have a fragment **A->B** in navigation graph.
**FragmentA** being the MainFragment (Top level destination)
**FragmentB** being the fragment that will edit/add values that will be reflected in MainFragment.

**Now, here's the root of the problem, when I edit data of Recyclerview in FragmentB, and press BACK button, it still updates/reflects data back to FragmentA. How is this even possible?**

When pressing back, It should just destroy fragment and shouldn't persist the changed data inside that fragment, however, it persists somehow and I cannot figure out how!!

**MORE INFORMATION**

In **fragmentB** I have a recyclerview, and when recyclerview item is clicked, I am as a test, changing dataset value to something else. And then I press back, It somehow still passes data to **FragmentA**.

**I have no observable data nor I am triggering observable data in MainViewModel() in anyway when items are changed in recyclerview, so it baffles me as to how that changes are persisted. When items are selected, it triggers observable and that list is pushed to recyclerview, after which changing inside recyclerview items shouldn't be preserved, if I choose to save, yes it should be, but definitely not when I press back button without performing any operation on that data.**

So I genuinely need an expert's guidance or different eyes because this could be a bug or something in navigation component or something is happening that I cannot understand.

Reyclerview in FRAGMENTB.

```
class CircleListAdapter:
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CircleListAdapter.CircleHolder>() {

    private var data = arrayListOf<CircleData>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CircleHolder{
        return CircleHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = data.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CircleHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentData = data.get(position)


        holder.binding.imageViewRadius.setOnClickListener{
            val radius = 2000
            currentData.radius =radius 
        
        }

    }

    class CircleHolder(val binding: CircleDataLayout) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {


        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): CircleHolder{
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = CircleDataLayout.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return CircleHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }

    fun setData(newData: ArrayList<CircleData>) {
        val circleDiffUtil = DataChangeUtil(data, newData)
        val diffUtilResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(champDiffUtil)
        data.clear()
        data.addAll(newData)
        diffUtilResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    fun getAdapterData(): ArrayList<CircleData> {
        
        return data
    }

    fun isDataFilledInRecyclerView() = data.size > 0
```

so above is the recyclerview that I use and when I click on this recyclerview item, I am setting `radius` as 2000. Internally, it changes data in **FragmentB**, after that when I press back button (Because let's say user decided not to save that data!) it shouldn't presist the data changed, i.e. radius to 2000 shouldn't be saved!.

however, that is not the case. When I press back button, **It passes value 2000 radius in FragmentA from FragmentB**

If you need any more information, feel free to comment, I am happy to provide information needed. I am using navigation component, Single activity application.

**MainViewModel is sharedViewmodel meaning that the same instance is shared among all fragments**

--update--

```
@parcelize
data class CircleData(
var radius: Float = 1f, 
val pointX: Float = 0f, 
val pointY: Float = 1f, 
val circleId: 1
) : Parcelable
```

**json that has CircleData**

```
[{
  "radius":12,
  "circleId":1,
  "pointX":0,
  "pointY":0
},
{
  "radius":10,
  "circleId":2,
  "pointX":0,
  "pointY":0
},
{
  "radius":24,
  "circleId":3,
  "pointX":0,
  "pointY":0
}]
```

**Viewmodel**

```
private var _selectedCircle: MutableLiveData<List<CircleData>> = MutableLiveData()
val selectedCircle: LiveData<List<CircleData>> get() = _selectedCircle
```

**inside fragmentB**

```
   mViewModel.selectedCircle.observe(viewlifecycleOwner) { circles ->
             mCircleListAdapter.setData(circles)
     }
```

So I am observing changes to liveData in **FragmentB**, and in `Adapter` changing the value of `CircleData` in Adapter item clicklistener when you check Recyclerview adapter code. Changes made there in adapter are reflecting in `FragmentA` when I press back button on `FragmentB`

Hope it gives the clear picture of what might be happening.

My thoughts:

I believe that when circleData instance with same value, i.e exact same ID and radius and X,Y points, when they are changed in `FragmentB`, hashCode() matches with all the previous same value circles; however, I don't think liveData should save the data specially when I am assigning the list of observed data class which has no connection to LiveData. So my question is that how is recyclerview list after passing to adapter is linked and able to transfer that data to `FragmentA`?

Steps:

1. `FragmentA` showing cirlces
2. Going to FragmentB, assigning CircleData list to `_selectedCircle`live data
3. step 2 triggeres observe and that list is now assigned to CircleListAdapter
4. changing the value of radius in CircleAdapter which will change the list data inside CircleAdapter.
5. Press back button on Toolbar in `FragmentB`, and changed value will be updated to all circles with same circleId and radius inside `FragmentA`.

So how the change in CircleAdapter list items, ie. `CircleData` list inside adapter which is inside `FragmentB` is passed to `FragmentA`?

Comment: You'll need to include FragmentA and FragmentB if you want us to debug an issue with the communication between FragmentA and FragmentB. As well as whatever ViewModels you are using that are shared between them both.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you for the comment and there's so much code in both fragments, is there anything specific you want to see? I am not changing viewmodel observable data in `FragmentB` so pressing back button shouldn't persist changes happened in recyclerview right?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I can give you an access to my repository if you are willing to take a  look at it.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I would appreciate if you would give your thoughts for this. I have genuinely debugged a lot and there's no trigger of setvalue method when locally changing data in recyclerview yet when I press back button, in another fragment, that value is updated.

Comment: You'll need to add the minimal set of code needed to reproduce your problem in the question itself. It sounds like your problem includes both FragmentA, FragmentB, and whatever ViewModels they are touching.

Comment: I have @parcelize data class and I have mutablelive val of that data class, i.e. `MutableLiveData<List<DataClass>>`, when I change one item of Dataclass it reflects in all fragments. I solved it by introducing unique key in another data classes and saving the result, but in my opinion this shouldn't happen, may be hashCode matched because of similar method and livedata updates every instance of that in all fragments, to me seems like an unintended side effect of live data...

Comment: @ianhanniballake I added rest of the code that applies to this and really connected to this.

Comment: What if you moved the `holder.binding.imageViewRadius.setOnClickListener` listener to the init{} of the `CircleHolder`?

Comment: I will recommend verify two things, change data in observe and change data using getAdapterData

Comment: It might not a problem related to recycleview, in this situation, I might consider using ListAdapter , which implement diff algorithm, and using data class copy and callback function, instead of using var in data class, but of course it might related to your project demand

Comment: @Zain I will not have the access to current position of items (circleData), like I do have in `OnBindViewHolder()` method. The scenario I have is that changing list items in Adapter reflects everywhere in the application which shouldn't happen because I am not triggering livedata or doing like `_selectedCircle.value = circleDataList`.

Comment: You can get the position with `bindingAdapterPosition` inside the ViewHolder

Comment: @KennyC Yes, it is not a recyclerview problem, the thing I want to understand is that how a change in list item is transferred to another fragment? The change I do in Adapter should be local in the list, yet somehow that minor change in radius, is passed to another fragment (I think all fragments too) somehow, even without triggering or passing it to livedata. Modifications are done which is fine in the list, but I didn't assign it to livedata so how other fragment knows what changed?

Comment: @Zain yes, true but I don't have the access to the list of data in `init{}` block. I do not think it matters where I change the value of that list, what's annoying is that how is that change is notified to another fragment? I just wanted to modify locally in `FragmentB` and show, when pressed back, should completely forget the change because it is done in list of adapter in `fragmentB`, but it saves and applies to every data object that has similar (i.e same hashcode I think) value in `FragmentA`

Comment: Regardless the issue of the LiveData, adding listeners in `onBindViewHolder()` method is not that good as that would be added every time the views are recycled when you just need a single listener for all the items and just a variable position. For the main issue, you'd add a log in the ViewModel and on the fragment back pressed callback. And see when the LiveData is really updated, does it on the back pressed action or something else like when the item is clicked on the RV. That would give some clue for the reason

Comment: Please add screenshot of FragmentB and A. How does a user save data after modifying the recyclerview? Is there any button for this?